# .htaccess : Include Non-Existent Sub Folder in URL

Tags: .htaccess

I'm using an E-Commerce platform to create static HTML pages, but it doesn't allow me to control a sub-folder location in the URL.  So I'm stuck with www.URL.com/staticPage

I need a total of 3 different sub-folders in the URL.  So for instance,         `www.URL.com/staticPage` 
would be `www.URL.com/overview/staticPage` , where I can't physically create the overview sub-folder folder.

I've tried a few variations of the below, but that folder doesn't actually exist.

```
RedirectMatch 301 overview http://www.URL.com/subfolder/overview
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(overview)[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /why-shebeest/%1 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^why-shebeest/(.+)$ $1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. 

RewriteRule ^(overview)/?$ why-shebeest/$1 [NC,L]

I would expect it to be URL.com/why-sheebest/overview , but there is no change in the URL or redirecting.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you.  The redirect does work.  Unfortunately, the end result is still the same.  The sub-folder doesn't actually exist on the server, so I get a 404.  I was under the impression there was a way to make a sub-folder display in the URL without it actually existing and resulting in a 404.

Comment: Thank you! Extremely helpful.

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.